# How to close one side of a TCP connection leaving other side hanging open? (No FIN or RST sent)

Tags: solaris, tcp, socket

I am trying to recreate a scenario where a Solaris client is connected to a Linux server via TCP socket, but the client side of the connection suddenly goes down without sending sending a FIN or RST packet. This is a very similar result to having the network cable between the client and server pulled.

Is there any command or series of commands in Solaris that might be able to recreate this situation without having to pull any network cables?

Comment: It's not clear from your question if the problem you have to debug is on the linux or the solaris side. Anyways with bridges and tap devices (tun/tap used to be available for solaris, too), you can "route" the connection through a small program like [taptap](https://www.headcrashers.org/comp/programs/taptap.html), which you could then `kill -STOP`.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably need something like setting up an ipfilter drop rule that matches that particular connection, then using [tcpdrop](https://github.com/reidmv/CATsfw/tree/master/CATtcpdrop) or something similar to tell Solaris to just wipe out the socket.

The ipfilter drop rule needs to be set up first, as otherwise the kernel may still respond with a RST packet when the first incoming packet after `tcpdrop` arrives. If you can afford to let the connections time out on their own at the Solaris side, then the `tcpdrop` is not absolutely necessary.

Note that `tcpdrop` uses an undocumented kernel interface, so there is no guarantee of it working with Solaris versions newer than it was made for.

If there is no other traffic to the same host that you might want to keep, another possibility is to add a blackhole route for the server host. But compared to just dropping a single TCP connection, that is a fairly blunt instrument that will kill all other connections to the same host as collateral damage.

See also: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/networking/tcpdrop-jsp-135583.html